# Nanopi M4V2 UART debugging

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, usb, uart, nanopi

I have a SBC Nanopi M4V2 (the board link is given below so as to read the specification). I want to use the UART port to debug/console to check what is wrong and why my board is not booting from micro SD. I am new to SBC after searching through internet I understood I need to debug using UART in the board. Hence I intend to buy a TTL to USB serial adapter. After search I got confused as there are many varieties. I am giving the link below can any one answer the below questions

1)Which variety will work with Nanopi M4V2 to debug during booting

2)What are main difference of each TTL to USB cable given in link 3(below)

link 1:- Nanopi M4V2 -> https://www.friendlyarm.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=268

link 2:- Nanopi M4V2 hardware spec -> http://wiki.friendlyarm.com/wiki/index.php/NanoPi_M4V2#Hardware_Spec

Link 2:- TTL to USb -> https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000120687489.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.70604c4dZP0BDG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1)Which variety will work with Nanopi M4V2 to debug during booting

The [model sold by FriendlyARM](https://www.friendlyarm.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=178&search=uar&description=true&category_id=0&sub_category=true) works on all the Nanopi devices I have used (and also on Raspberry).

[image: USB to TTL Serial Cable - Debug / Console Cable for Pi]

Note that this model uses a CH340G chip that someone describes as [unreliable](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/54641) although I have had no problem so far. They also mention the CP2102 which is very common. I use both.

This adapter has 4 pins but you will probably use only 3 since you have an external power supply.

> 2)What are main difference of each TTL to USB cable given in link
>   3(below)

I can't really answer that question but one has 6 pins and the two others have 5. They could work but I would stick to models that are known to be suitable. CP2102 should be safe but verify the number of pins and cable terminations (should be female on both ends). You might want to use **jumper cables** instead of the [JST connectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JST_connector) shown in picture.

NB: you may have to **activate** the debug port in your OS as it may not be available by default at boot - in your case this is UART2. You may have to adapt the **Uboot** command line too. So if you see nothing in your terminal window when the device boots don't worry this could be normal.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. The problem is FriendlyARM is not shipping to my country due to covid-19. Well few more queries from your post  1) what is jumper cables and why should that be used?   2) I am using armbian Buster for Nanopi M4v2 are you are if debug port is activate?    3)My Nanopi M4V2 is not booting with the SD card that came with even though I formated and flashed several times. I tried different SD card it worked with buster. I thought to use bionic and flashed it. It stopped working there after even buster will not work with second card. Any Idea?

Comment: I think that's a whole range of new questions that should be asked elsewhere (on Linux subforum probably). The point of using jumper cables is that they are longer simply (in case the supplied cables are too short for your purpose but that's it). As for the other questions, you need to explain in more details which OS you're trying to run and what steps you performed and error messages if any. That's too many questions and unknown details

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will create another post in Linux forum